# Why does not form send post request on submit in my AngularJS app after creating controller for the form partial?

Tags: angularjs, forms

I created simple form for login:

```
<form   role="form" method="post"  >
     <label for="email">Email</label>
         <input type="email" name="email" id="email"  required />
         <label for="password">Password</label>
         <input type="password" name="password" id="password"required />
         <button type="submit"  >Login</button>
 </form>
```

And this part of code is responsible for routing and specifies the controller:

```
angular.module('app',['ng-token-auth','ngRoute', 'templates'])
    .config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider',
        function($routeProvider,$locationProvider) {
            $routeProvider
                .when('/auth/sign_in', {
                    templateUrl: 'auth/login.html',
                    controller: 'loginCtrl'
                })
```

When there is no controller in my code I receive:

```
 Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'loginCtrl' is not a function, got undefined
```

and there is POST request after form submit

But after creating controller

```
angular.module('app')
.controller('loginCtrl',function(){

})
```

there is no any of requests or any other reaction on form submit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly because you don't submit the form (AngularJs prevents the default action). So you can either use [ng-click on submit button](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick) or [ng-submit on form](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSubmit).

```
<button type="submit" ng-click="postData()">Login</button>
```

Inside your controller you can declare the function that will be triggered once you click on the submit button and use **$http.post()** to post the data to your server.

```
    $scope.postData = function() {
       // DO whatever you want after the button is clicked
       $http.post ...
    }
```

Check out the Angular documentation on $http for more information.
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http